# Apache serve local link as web page?

Tags: linux

My basic setup is on a Qnap TS-251 NAS box, which uses Qapache, but I think the problem is really a basic Apache setup that, to me, does not have an obvious solution and all the searching hasn't shown me a solution.

So, what I am trying to do is have Apache serve a web page based on a local "shared link". The link looks like this:

```
https://192.168.x.xxx/share.cgi?ssid=0h5NjVW
```

When I put that into my browser, it pulls up a very nice QNAP UI of the folders and files I want to share via the Internet.

I currently have this working as a webpage but all I get is the standard "Index Page" plain text formatting of folders and files.

How can I put in a directive to properly serve up that link?

Thanks!

[edit] 
Here is the current entry for this webpage in httpd.conf:
In httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "/share/Multimedia/Other">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Here is the entry in /opt/Qapache/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:88>
#    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/share/Multimedia/Other"
    ServerName mywebsite.pagekite.me
    ErrorLog "/share/Multimedia/Other/error_log.csv"
    CustomLog "/share/Multimedia/Other/access_log.csv" common
</VirtualHost>
```

This does work and serves up the right folders/files, but is in plain text with no friendly layout/formatting like the shared link provides.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want FancyIndex, see this URL:

http://ram.kossboss.com/apache-pretty-indexing/

What do you mean exactly by

> currently have this working as a webpage but all I get is the standard "Index Page" plain text formatting of folders and files.
>
> How can I put in a directive to properly serve up that link?

Do you mean to the internet? If so you will need to do portforwarding at your router and ensure that your QNap box has a route back via your portforwarding NAT device.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at FancyIndex.     

    "Do you mean to the internet? If so you will need to do portforwarding     at your router and ensure that your QNap box has a route back via your portforwarding NAT device." Yes, as shown this is working as a normal webpage. Pagekite handles all dns registrations, etc...no port forwarding needed. This is working for remote users. By plain text it is like you would see at github if you went to a list of available folders/files to download. QNAP through the shared link, has a very 'pretty' layout built in, so would like to use that link

Comment: No more ideas, anyone? Original question was how to use local share link as webpage using Apache.

Answer (score 0):

The "shared link" I asked about is a cgi script. Once I determined that and its location in the QNAP QTS file structure, then a little research found many references to running cgi scripts using standard Apache directives. I don't have it actually working yet, but I am confident that is the best approach.

Thanks to those that replied.